# How to respond with request body using sinon.fakeServer?

Tags: javascript, sinon

[Sinon documentation](http://sinonjs.org/releases/v2.3.8/fake-xhr-and-server/#serverrespondwithresponse) states that it's possible to access the request object:

> `server.respondWith(response);`
>
> [...]
>
> When the response is a `Function`, it will be passed the request object. You must manually call respond on it to complete the request.

But the naive approach doesn't seem to work:

```
const server = sinon.server.create();

server.respondWith(request => request.requestBody);
```

(Throws response as an error in my Mocha suite).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `server.respond();`. After that you will have `server.requests` object. 
For example in qunit:

```
server.respond([200, { "Content-type": "application/json" }, "OK"]);
assert.ok(server.requests.length > 0, "Response received");
assert.ok(server.requests[0].status == 200, "Status is 200");
```